# AngularJS OrderBy problems

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

So i'm learning angularJS and was messing around with the ng-repeat, and $http service.

I picked a webservice to return some data, and put it into the ng-repeat and that all works fine.

I want to be able to re-organise the table A-Z, Z-A by color name, but I cant get it working. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the structure of the JSON i'm getting back.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wshekyls/bKGPj/

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">Sort :
<select ng-model="selectedColumn">
<option value="name">A-Z</option>
<option value="-name">Z-A</option>
</select>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Cloth</th>
<th>Leather</th>
<th>Metal</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="color in colorData | orderBy:selectedColumn">
<td>{{color.name}}</td>
<td style="background: rgb({{color.cloth.rgb.join()}});">{{color.cloth.rgb}}</td>
<td style="background: rgb({{color.leather.rgb.join()}});">{{color.cloth.rgb}}</td>
<td style="background: rgb({{color.metal.rgb.join()}});">{{color.cloth.rgb}}</td>
</tr>
</table> <pre>{{colorData | json}}</pre>
<!-- !!!!!!!!! -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function testCtrl($scope, $http) {

$http.get('https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/colors.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.colorData = data.colors;
});

$scope.selectedColumn = 'name';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return data is not an array and orderBy only works with array...

You should push all your data into array on order to work with `orderBy` if you rearrange your code like this it will work...

```
$http.get('https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/colors.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.colorData = [];
    angular.forEach(data.colors, function(color){
       $scope.colorData.push(color);     
    });
});
```

here is workin [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GDyf7/)...